# Finding a Row between two Spreadsheets and then finding the Row containing a value from that first row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script where it searches between two Spreadsheets Columns A and B for the first row that has different values.   However after it finds that row with the different values, I want it to get that row, get the value in Spreadsheet 1 and find that specific value in the Spreadsheet 2.  And then get the row of that value in Spreadsheet 2. I made this code that performs the first part well, but when i try to get the second part I can't seem to think of how to put it together.

```
function checkAndPlace() {
  var sos = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet 1");
  var sas = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sos);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange('F2').setValue('RUNNING')
  var Avals = s1.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast1 = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var s1LastRow = s1.getLastRow()+1;                           
  var Sheet1DataRange = s1.getRange(1,1,s1LastRow,2);
  var Sheet1BDataRange = s1.getRange(1,2,s1LastRow,1);
  var Sheet1Data = Sheet1DataRange.getValues();
  var Sheet1BData = Sheet1BDataRange.getValues();
  var Sheet1length = Sheet1Data.length;
  var sos2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet 2");
  var sas2 = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sos2);
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s2 = ss2.getActiveSheet();
  var Avals2 = s2.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast2 = Avals2.filter(String).length;
  var s2LastRow = s2.getLastRow()+1;
  var Sheet2DataRange = s2.getRange(1,1,s2LastRow,2);
  var Sheet2BDataRange = s2.getRange(1,2,s2LastRow,1);
  var Sheet2Data = Sheet2DataRange.getValues();
  var Sheet2BData = Sheet2BDataRange.getValues();
  var Sheet2length = Sheet2Data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < Sheet1Data.length; i++) {
    var s1data = Sheet1Data[i][0];
    Logger.log(s1data)
    var s1Bdata = Sheet1BData[i][0];
    Logger.log(s1Bdata)
    var s2data = Sheet2Data[i][0];
    Logger.log(s2data)
    var s2Bdata = Sheet2BData[i][0];
    Logger.log(s2Bdata)
    if (s1data + s1Bdata != s2data + s2Bdata){
      var falseRow = i+1
      var falseRowARange = s2.getRange(falseRow,1,1,2);
      var falseRowAName = falseRowARange.getValues();
      var falseRowBRange = s2.getRange(falseRow,2,1,1);
      var falseRowBName = falseRowBRange.getValues();
      Logger.log("Line: "+i+". Sheets are NOT equal. Sheet1 = "+s1data+", Sheet2 = "+s2data);
      for (var j = 0; j < Sheet2Data.length; j++) {
        var s1data = Sheet1Data[j][0];
        Logger.log(s1data)
        var s1Bdata = Sheet1BData[j][0];
        Logger.log(s1Bdata)
!!!!        var falsejdata = falseRowAName[j][0]; "Cannot read property 0"
        Logger.log(falsejdata)
        var falsejBdata = falseRowBName[j][0];
        Logger.log(falsejBdata)
        if(falsejdata + falsejBdata == s1data + s1Bdata) {
          var trueRow = j+1
          Logger.log(trueRow)
        }
    }
      return false;
    }
    else {
      Logger.log("Line: "+i+". Sheets are equal, value: "+s1data);
    }
  }
}
```

it keeps reading "cannot read property '0' from undefined."  I marked the line in the code where it shows this.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I have a spreadsheet that keeps getting updated with more information and I need to know what rows were updated in order to have the script add cells to those rows with information. So Spreadsheet 1 compares it self to a mirror spreadsheet 2.  It finds which values are different and then decides to delete or add a row.  But determining which one for it to do has been an issue.  I first made it add or delete if it was bigger or smaller than the mirror sheet. But if it gets updated very quickly, it finds it self deleting rows it's suppose to add and gets everything out of wack.  So I decided I want the value from the different row from spreadsheet 1 to find that value in spreadsheet 2 to determine if it should be deleted, added, or start the `checkAndPlace()` function from the start instead of doing anything. I then want to find the value from the different row from spreadsheet 2 to search for itself in spreadsheet 1 to see if it still exists in there or not and which row?  so it can compare the difference of the rows it exists in.

But right now I don't even know if I need two different loops to make this work or how to even right it out.  Just looking at my code, you can see how it got all kinds of confusing. I am relatively new, so maybe there's something simple I overlooked or didn't know about.

Edit: Another piece of information is that Spreadsheet 1 gets information fed into it from a query coming from a spreadsheet that is edited multiple times a day.  This edit causes an install-able onChange() function to run the checkAndPlace() function.

Comment: Will your script always be run while you are in front of it or do you plan to run it from say a time based trigger?

Comment: Oh good question.  Let me add that to my question.  But to answer your question.  It is a installable onChange() Trigger that activates this function.  The change is whenever the query that the information is coming from is updated, which can happen multiple times throughout the day.

Comment: So there won't really be an activeSheet() because the Spreadsheet will be openByID() and it will only be running on the server.  (i.e. no User Interface) so perhaps you should start with `var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id'); var s1=ss.getSheetByName('name');`

Comment: `ss.getRange('F2')` should include the sheetname like this `ss.getRange('SheetName!F2')`

Comment: Are you Searching for differences between Spreadsheet1 sheet1 ColumnA/B and Spreadsheet2  sheet1 ColumnA/B?

Comment: How do the updates in your spreadsheet occur.  User Edits Perhaps? or other? Please specify.

Comment: Getting Sheets by name is unnecessary because there is only one sheet per spreadsheet.  Spreadsheet 1 is open and being used the entire time so making it active is a must.  From everything down until ``for (var j = 0...)`` has worked.  It's how i found the "falseRow" but I haven't found out how to then search the values from the falseRow into Spreadsheet 2 to see if there's a match.  Basically Spreadsheet 1.getRange(FalseRow,1,1,2).getValues() search columns A,B in SSpreadsheet 2 for those values.  Get Row in spreadsheet 2 with those values. else If no value, do other thing.

Comment: The onChange() function runs anytime the query on the sheet changes.  It also changes when anyone edits the sheet manually.  Which also happens because it's a  sign out sheet.  But the issue isn't with the signing out, it's with it automatically updating correctly by adding cells and deleting them in the correct order as to not get confused as to which to do.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I got it. came up with the values I was expecting to see.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < Sheet1Data.length; i++) {
    var s1data = Sheet1Data[i][0];// s1 is spreadsheet 1's sheet.
    Logger.log(s1data)
    var s1Bdata = Sheet1BData[i][0];
    Logger.log(s1Bdata)
    var s2data = Sheet2Data[i][0];
    Logger.log(s2data)
    var s2Bdata = Sheet2BData[i][0];
    Logger.log(s2Bdata)
    if (s1data + s1Bdata != s2data + s2Bdata){
      var falseRow = i+1
      var falseRow2ARange = s2.getRange(falseRow,1,1,1);//s2 is spreadsheet 2's sheet.
      var falseRow2AName = falseRow2ARange.getValues();
      var falseRow2BRange = s2.getRange(falseRow,2,1,1);
      var falseRow2BName = falseRow2BRange.getValues();
      Logger.log('falseRow is '+falseRow+' and its value is '+falseRow2AName+' '+falseRow2BName+'.');
      Logger.log("Line: "+i+". Sheets are NOT equal. Sheet1 = "+s1data+", Sheet2 = "+s2data);
      for (var j = 0; j < Sheet1Data.length; j++) {
        var s1data = Sheet1Data[j][0];
        Logger.log(s1data)
        var s1Bdata = Sheet1BData[j][0];
        Logger.log(s1Bdata)
        if(falseRow2AName + falseRow2BName == s1data + s1Bdata) {
          var trueRow = j+1
          Logger.log(trueRow)
        }
}
}
}
```